# Multiple connection strings, one repository with dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

Right now I've got a basic IRepository that takes in IConnect (contains a string value).  I'm running into an issue getting my DI (structuremap) to determine which connection string to use.  In theory, if I use an attribute on the entity, I could write up a registry/scanner that determines this but I wonder if there's an easier way to do it?

right now I have something like this

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(factory =>
{
    factory.For<IConnect>().Singleton().Use<ConnectToMarket>()
        .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
        .Is(_marketConnectionString);
    //and some other stuff
});
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could derive different repositories from different interfaces. Say you have a `IMarketRepository` which is constructed with the market connection string. So all repositories that use the `marketconnectionstring` are constructed with that connection string (provided you do the registration correctly).

I'm assuming you don't have to use the same repository for multiple connectionstrings?

Another solution could be to make multiple implementations of `IConnectionString` or something which you can specify in the constructor.

Both solutions are not really nice I must say.

Comment: This is exactly what I did.  I made a IConnectToMarket : IConnect then created a MarketRepository<T>.  To ensure someone didn't try to tell an entity to the wrong database, I added ILiveInMarket constraint.  It kinda sucks, but it works